Can I add OKTA login in a Google Chrome extension's sidepanel without having to login in another window?
I'm creating a Google Chrome extension that has a sidepanel, and I want users to be able to login using OKTA authentication. I'm using Vue3, if that makes any difference. Right now, there's a button that opens up a tab for the user to login to, but I want to be able to have the user enter credentials right in the sidepanel. Is that possible? On an semi-related note, this app will be in Vue3 -- so any suggestions/tips would be useful. Thanks!
The major problem I have is using the vue router as okta requires a redirect to a "base url" but since the app is an extension, there is no base url.

I'm not familiar with OKTA api but the documentation seems to suggest you can do what you're asking via embedded authentication.  Also, addressing your second question, there are ways to pass redirect events to chrome extensions
